# I am trying to complete a basic string methods exercise. Please advise where I am going wrong. Thanks

Tags: python, string, function, conditional-statements

Question:
Write a function `‘name_length(name)’` that will take a `string` and `print` out:-

‘Your name is long’ if
the length of name is bigger than 5, otherwise `print` ‘Your name is short’.

• Eg: calling `name_length(‘Joe’)` should print out ‘Your name

```
def name_length(name):
    if len(name) > 5:
        print('Your name is long')
    else:
        print('Your name is short')

name_length(Joe)
```

Comment: the code looks correct, the problem could be that you don't have a `Joe` object and probably you need `name_length("Joe")`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

I think where you're going wrong is that in your last line:

```
 name_length(Joe)
```

The word Joe should have quotation marks around it, as it is not a variable, so it should look like this:

```
name_length('Joe')
```

If you wanted you could include a variable in that last line and make the whole code look like this:

```
def name_length(name):
  if len(name) > 5:
    print('Your name is long')
  else:
    print('Your name is short')

your_name = input('What is your name? ')
name_length(your_name)
```